# Template Button for reuse in code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm sorry if this is very obvious, but it's been years since I used C#, and I can't seem to find the correct google search term for this.

I am trying to create a button template in XAML that will be used in a, for example, 2x2 grid. **This button has to be added in code**, because the user should be able to define how many buttons he wants during runtime. The button is supposed to contain another button and a label.

```
<Window x:Class="Soundboard.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="750" Width="1200">
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="myButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Canvas x:Name="mainCanvas">
            <Button x:Name="childButton" Height="30" Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/picture.png"/>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
            <Label x:Name="nameLabel" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></Label>
            </Canvas>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="myGrid">
</Grid>
```

I can call the button fine by adding this line in XAML myGrid (to test)

```
    <Button Template="{StaticResource myButton}" Height="200" Width="200" Margin="300,0,0,0"></Button>
    <Button Template="{StaticResource smyButton}" Height="200" Width="200" Margin="0,0,0,0"></Button>
```

But I don't seem to be able to find a way to add that button in code. This is one of my tries that will not work:

```
Button b = (Button)FindResource("myButton");
b.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, r); // r is int from row for loop
b.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, c); // c is int from column for loop
myGrid.Children.Add(b);
```

But b will always be null. Can someone help me? I am guessing I am using some wrong method in the XAML, but I really have no idea at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myButton` is a ControlTemplate instead of a Button as currently being accessed in the code, so you may modify the code as follows

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Template = (ControlTemplate)FindResource("myButton");
```

so in above example you retrieve the ControlTemplate via FindResource method and apply it to a newly created button.

rest remains the same

Answer (score -1):

Like this line and it has been used on app.xaml files :

```
  <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries> 
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default"> 
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent" /> 
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent" /> 
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxItemPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush" Color="#f7f6f6" /> 
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxItemPressedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent" /> 
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxItemPressedForegroundThemeBrush" Color="#f7f6f6" /> 
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent" /> 
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxItemSelectedDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#66FFFFFF" /> 
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxItemSelectedDisabledForegroundThemeBrush" Color="#99000000" /> 
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush" Color="#f7f6f6" /> 
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent" /> 
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent" /> 
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxBorderThemeBrush" Color="Transparent" /> 
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush" Color="#66FFFFFF" /> 
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxFocusBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#f7f6f6" /> 
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxForegroundThemeBrush" Color="#f7f6f6" /> 

            </ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: pushpraj had the answer I was looking for. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Don't know what question you were trying to answer, but it isn't this one.